# append new markup in .aspx from code behind

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to add some extra texts in an existing .aspx page in runtime. But not finding any suitable way to do it.

Is there any way to append new markups to an .aspx page from code behind in runtime?

for example:

I have this in an .aspx page-

```
<html>
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
```

And i want to append this from code behind-

```
    <div>
    hghjggjg
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Thank you.

Comment: I don't know if your ASP.NET page will even work if you don't have complete well-formed HTML (the closing form, body, and html tags).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dynamically...
..aspx

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true"     CodeBehind="xx.ascx.cs"   Inherits="xx.layouts.xxSublayout" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="System.Web" Namespace="System.Web.UI" TagPrefix="asp" %>
<asp:LiteralControl runat="server" ID="openingTag" />
<asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" id="contentPanel" />
<asp:LiteralControl runat="server" ID="closingTag" />
```

code behind..add a div with text to some method other than PAGE_LOAD...

```
 var inputWrapper = new HtmlGenericControl("div"){ID = "d1"};
        inputWrapper.Attributes.Add("class", "yourcssclass");
        inputWrapper.InnerText = "hghjggjg";
        contentPanel.Controls.Add(inputWrapper);
```

to persist tag postback...

```
            //add div ID to list, add list to session so it can be recreated on the page_INIT, this must be done or btn will NOT exist when "Get vCard" is clicked.
            PostbackIDs.Add(inputWrapper.ID);
            Session["pb"] = PostbackIDs;
```

on INit...

```
//Must recreate controls from session, so label is existing
       if (Session["pb"] != null)
        {
            var pblist = (List<string>)Session["pb"];
            foreach (var id in pblist)
            {                   
                // label
                var inputWrapper= new HtmlGenericControl("div") { ID = id };
                inputWrapper.Attributes.Add("class", "yourcssclass");                    
                contentPanel.Controls.Add(inputWrapper);
            }
        }
```

Since the INIT method is hit before page load, the ID of the control will be in place to add text to it..

Comment: Your buttons and tags w text will persist, creating them dynamically in the page load BUT if you create dynamically elsewhere you'll need to possibly recreate the controls in INIT as garrison stated..

Answer (score 0):

Create `HTMLElement` instances in the back-end, fill them with data and add them to the control/page.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `Label` to your ASPX and modify the `Text` property at runtime.

If you want to add controls at runtime instead, `PlaceHolder` is a good control to investigate.  But keep in mind that these dynamically declared controls will not persist automatically through a `PostBack`.

Comment: I am not wanting to add text to a label or text control.

Comment: Then I suggest you update your question and be more specific with what you are attempting to accomplish.